# Implement onclick event

Tags: html, onclick, jqgrid

I have new UI where inside jqgrid column there is icon ,if I click it I need to hit on function.

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
                    return '<div class="text-center email_production">' +
                        '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#toMailModal" class="icon_color pr-2" ><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>' +
                        '</div>';
                }
```

where to implement onclick function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the formatter should return string you can by example add onclick="myFunction()" in the definition or after the grid data is loaded to (use gridComplate event) to bind a function to the element with certain class

for the first case

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
                    return '<div class="text-center email_production">' +
                        '<a data-toggle="modal" onclick="myFunction()" data-target="#toMailModal" class="icon_color pr-2" ><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>' +
                        '</div>';
                }
```

and define your global myFunction()

For the second case

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
....
gridComplete : function() {
    $(".pr-2").on("click", function(){
        // do whatever you want
    });
}
...
});
```

Where pr-2 is a class of the a href element